# CSV separator auto-detection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I detect the CSV separator from a string in Javascript/NodeJS?

Which is the standard algorithm?

Note that the separator is not a  comma always. The most common separators being `;`, `,` and `\t` (tab).

Comment: Here's how Python does it: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/csv.py?view=markup#l162

Comment: What module are you using to parse the CSV?

Comment: @Blender It would be nice to port it for javascript. I am not a python expert... and I don't see a similar question on SO.

Comment: @Johnツ: It's well-commented and the regular expressions should work fine if you don't use named groups. That's really all there is to it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A possible algorithm for getting the likely separator(s) is pretty simple, and assumes the data is well-formed:

1. For every delimiter,

   1. For every line,

      1. Split the line by the delimiter, check the `length`.
      2. If its `length` is *not* equal to the last line's length, this is not a valid delimiter.

Proof of concept (doesn't handle quoted fields):

```
function guessDelimiters (text, possibleDelimiters) {
    return possibleDelimiters.filter(weedOut);

    function weedOut (delimiter) {
        var cache = -1;
        return text.split('\n').every(checkLength);

        function checkLength (line) {
            if (!line) {
                return true;
            }

            var length = line.split(delimiter).length;
            if (cache < 0) {
                cache = length;
            }
            return cache === length && length > 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The `length > 1` check is to make sure the `split` didn't just return the whole line. Note that this returns an array of possible delimiters - if there's more than one item, you have an ambiguity problem.

Comment: this is nice code but very hard to read. i would like it refactored to include csv line break detection too but i cant because of how the function is written.

Comment: does not work well with "tab" as a delimiter

Comment: screws up if there is one row with an extra delimiter at the end

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is using the `detect` method from the [csv-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-string#detectinput--string--string) package:

> detect(input : String) : String Detects the best separator.

```
    var CSV = require('csv-string');

    console.log(CSV.detect('a,b,c')); // OUTPUT : ","
    console.log(CSV.detect('a;b;c')); // OUTPUT : ";"
    console.log(CSV.detect('a|b|c')); // OUTPUT : "|"
    console.log(CSV.detect('a\tb\tc'));// OUTPUT : "\t"
```

Comment: Thank you this package looks very complete. They even have a create read stream function.

Comment: Their detect delimiter function just finds the first occurance of one of these `[',', ';', '|', '\t']`. Ok most of the time I guess, but could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

This solution allows to detect the csv separator only for the top lines and handles quoted fields by using [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse).

It can be useful for large csv file to avoid reading the whole file several times.

```
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
const fs = require('fs')

function detectCsvDelimiter(file, maxLineCount, delimiters = [',', ';', '\t']) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Read only maxLineCount lines
        let stream = fs.createReadStream(file, { 
                 flags: 'r', encoding: 'utf-8', bufferSize: 64 * 1024 });
        let lineCounter = 0;
        let data = '';
        stream.on("data", (moreData) => {
            data += moreData;
            lineCounter += data.split("\n").length - 1;
            if (lineCounter > maxLineCount + 1) {
                stream.destroy();
                // Remove invalid last line
                resolve(data.split('\n').slice(0, maxLineCount));
            }
        });
        stream.on("error", (err) => reject(err));
        stream.on("end", () => resolve(data.split("\n")));
    }).then(lines => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const csvData = lines.join("\n");
            const validDelimiters = delimiters.filter(delimiter => {
                let isValid = true;
                // csv-parse throw error by default 
                // if the number of columns is inconsistent between lines
                try {
                    const rows = parse(csvData, {delimiter});
                    isValid = rows.some(row => row.length > 1);
                } catch (e) {
                    isValid = false;
                }
                return isValid;
            });
            resolve(validDelimiters);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function delimiter(csvText) {
    t = t.split("\n")[0];
    let delArray = [',', ';', '|', '    '];
    let comma = samiclon = pipe = tab = 0;
    delArray.forEach((e, i) => {
        if (i === 0) {
            comma = t.split(e).length;
        } else if (i === 1) {
            samiclon = t.split(e).length;
        } else if (i === 2) {
            pipe = t.split(e).length;
        } else if (i === 3) {
            tab = t.split(e).length;
        }
    });
    let tmpArray1 = [comma, samiclon, pipe, tab]
    let tmpArray = [comma, samiclon, pipe, tab];
    let maxLen = tmpArray.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0];
    let delimiter_i = 0;
    tmpArray1.forEach((e, i) => {
        if (maxLen === e) {
            delimiter_i = i;
        }
    });
    if (delimiter_i === 0) {
        return ',';
    } else if (delimiter_i === 1) {
        return ';'
    } else if (delimiter_i === 2) {
        return '|'
    } else if (delimiter_i === 3) {
        return '    '
    }
}
```

Comment: this is probably the best solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found Zirak's answer good in theory, but in practice it failed in many particular places.

Here are some examples that would fail and thus the method would return no delimiter :

- a trailing delimiter (by mistake) : test,test1,test2,
- missing cells without delimiters: test,test1

This is the most convenient and elegant solution :

```
let columnData = row.split(/,|;|\|| /);
```

What sucks here is if there is two delimiters that appear in a row, then this fails.

Say you want to seperate this data: "test,tes|t1,test2".

The above code produces an array that looks like this :
[test, tes, t1, test2]... No good.

Here is a more robust solution I wrote that was inspired by "the programmers" answer:

```
const rowSplitChars = this.determineCSVLineBreak(text);
const columnSplitChars = this.determineCSVDelimiter(text, rowSplitChars);



  private determineCSVLineBreak(text: any): string {
    try {
      const delArray = ["\r\n", "\n", "\r"];
      const rnrnArray = 
        [text.match(/\r/g).length
        ,text.match(/\n/g).length
        ,text.match(/\r\n/g).length];
      return delArray[this.getMaxIndexInArray(rnrnArray)];
    } catch {
      this.handleError('Error determining CSV file line break character.');
      return '';
    }
  }

  private determineCSVDelimiter(text: any, rowSplitChars: string): string {
    const t = text.split(rowSplitChars)[0];
    const delArray = [',', ';', '|', '    '];
    const countArray = 
      [t.split(delArray[0]).length
      ,t.split(delArray[1]).length
      ,t.split(delArray[2]).length
      ,t.split(delArray[3]).length];
    return delArray[this.getMaxIndexInArray(countArray)];
  }

  private getMaxIndexInArray(countArray: any[]) {
    let max = countArray[0];
    let maxIndex = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < countArray.length; i++) {
      if (countArray[i] > max) {
        maxIndex = i;
        max = countArray[i];
      }
    }
    return maxIndex;
  }
```